# Get-AzureRmResourceGroup : The term 'Get-AzureRmResourceGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to retrieve a resource group name from my Azure subscription in PowerShell:

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | select resourcegroupname
```

But I get the following error:

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup : The term 'Get-AzureRmResourceGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | select resourcegroupname
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzureRmResourceGroup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have PowerShell 5.0 and have imported the latest Azure module. Why is this not included?

Comment: What is the version of Azure PowerShell Cmdlets have you installed? I have the latest version and I am able to execute this Cmdlet.

Comment: It is 3.3.0 for me after running ``Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh``.

Comment: Me too. What do you see when you execute `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name AzureRM.Resources`?

Comment: It just returns a new line. I don't get a value.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the installation. Would you try reinstalling them?

Comment: Which module should I reimport?

Comment: @santafebound : You have to use Azure module only. But seems like the installation has not happened properly. Could you please try downloading that from other repo,import-module one more time  and give it a try.

Comment: After using ``Get-InstalledModule`` I see that my Azure.Storage and AzureRM.profile are version 2.4.0, whereas Azure is 3.3.0. Would that be a problem?

Comment: Okay AzureRM was not even installed. I ran ``Install-Module AzureRM`` and now the command above works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was missing the AzureRM dependency so I had to run the following command: `Install-AzureRM`. Afterwards, `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | select resourcegroupname` executed successfully.

Comment: If possible, please mark your answer, it will help more person.

Comment: It makes me wait another 11 hours. I will tomorrow.

Comment: This command Install-AzureRM has failed to me and I haven't found any documentation about it. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: I think he meant to write "Install-Module AzureRM"

Answer (score 17):

You need to get the Azure RM module installed first by using the following command:

```
Install-Module AzureRM
```

Then you need to import the module for use:

```
Import-Module AzureRM
```

Comment: The Az module seems to overlap with this one. This isn't working for me. I even tried this with the -AllowClobber which forced it to be installed but then the import line failed with errors indicating the assembly was already loaded. There seems to be overlap between the AzureRm and Az modules and the commands aren't working for me no matter what I do.

Comment: Sorry for late reply to this but it may help others. Currently Az and AzureRM are not compatible with each other. Az is for PS Core as it's cross platform and is expected to replace AzureRM however to this date not all functionality has been ported across. The commands are supposed to be shorter with increased stability etc.

In short using Az is a better option as it will be used as the future standard, if you are not restricted by it's current limitations.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem in Powershell 7.3